# compile gradle library project fails

Tags: android, gradle

My project structure looks like this:

```
-project
--settings.gradle
--build.gradle
--src

--libA
 ---src
---build.gradle

--libB
---src
---build.gradle

--libC
----build.gradle
```

Main build.gradle has this dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    compile project('libA')
    compile project('libB')
    compile project('libC')
}
```

LibA LibB and LibC are library project.
The problem: LibraryC depends on LibraryA and Library B. When I compile I get errors that Library C cannot find symbols of Library A or B. 
When I try to add this to build.gradle of LibC

```
compile project('libA')
```

I get an error that the path is not found. I did not find a way to specify a path if both project are on the same sub hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libC/build.gradle` needs to have:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":libA")
    compile project(":libB")
}
```

`":libA"` is an absolute project path. The leading `":"` denotes the root project.

In most cases, the root project doesn't have any source code, and doesn't declare any dependencies.